# what is with open as f using rb mode?

Tags: python, file

Could you please help me to understand what is this line of code?

`with open(f'{linear_rl_trader_models}/scaler.pkl', 'rb') as f:`

```
 ` scaler = pickle.load(f)`
```

I know what is open but the first part of open is not a directory.
why we have f'{}/...? I mean why {}?
could you please give me source or explain it? thanks,

Comment: It's a string formatting syntax. It's equal to 
'{}/scaler.pkl/'.format(linear_rl_trader_models).

Comment: That is an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). `{linear_rl_trader_models}` is replaced by whatever the variable `linear_rl_trader_models` is. That is probably a path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [formatted string literal (f-string)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals). F-strings are used to:

> include the value of Python expressions inside a string by prefixing the string with `f` or `F` and writing expressions as `{expression}`.

In this instance, you could think of it as a concatenation of strings, but in a more succinct format. In this way, your example could be thought of as:

```
with open(str(linear_rl_trader_models) + '/scaler.pkl', 'rb') ...
```

It's simply a string that contains the value of the `linear_rl_trader_models` variable, followed by `'/scaler.pkl'`

Comment: I am a little confused because when we use open, we give the name of file not the variables!

Comment: @hghg Indeed, and the name of the file is represented a string. It would be the same thing as defining a variable and assigning it the path beforehand, and then passing that variable into the `open()` function.